# How to write function with the matching const modifier on argument and return types?

Tags: c++, templates, types

I want to write a function that extracts a pointer field from a struct. The requirement is that if I pass the struct as a const argument, the returned type should be const. If not, the returned type should not be const.

For instance,

```
struct S {
    char *p;
};

// approach 1: two overload functions with duplicate body
auto extract(S &input) -> int * {
    return reinterpret_cast<int *>(input.p + 12);
}
auto extract(const S &input) -> const int * {
    return reinterpret_cast<const int *>(input.p + 12);
}

// approach 2: macro
#define macro_extract(input) (reinterpret_cast<int *>(input.p + 12))
```

Is there any trick in template or latest C++ standard that can write a strongly typed function without duplicating the body?

EDIT:
Changed the example a bit to reflect more accurately of the real problem.

Comment: Your edit changed the meaning of the question. Now your function bodies are different and *not* duplicated.

Comment: If you consider the return type as some abstract type `R`, and replace those cast with R, then it is still the same. Of course in the real code, the body would be like 30 lines of code. Duplicating 29 of them is still bad IMO.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Then the accepted answer doesn't seem to fully answer the question. Perhaps using the `if constexpr` approach in @Vasilij's solution in addition will work for the different line of code.

Comment: Well, you answered first, and I got my solution (adding the `R` to the template) based on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution with a single function template:

```
template<typename T, 
         typename = std::enable_if_t<
                      std::is_same_v<
                        std::remove_cv_t<
                          std::remove_reference_t<T>>, S>>>
auto extract(T&& input) 
  -> std::conditional_t<
       std::is_const_v<
         std::remove_reference_t<T>>, int const *, int *> 
{
    return input.p;
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6EMeYE).

I think it goes without saying that you'd be better off with an overload set. If the function body is large, you can still call the non-const version from the const overload, and add the const there.

Comment: It indeed looks overkill. But wouldn't calling the other function creates infinite recursion, since the only difference in the function signature is the const?

Comment: Hmm, you might be right. The infinite recursion could be solved with a tag-type, or simply a default boolean parameter. Still a better option than the template version.

Comment: Or `const_cast`.

Comment: Aah yes, or `const_cast` indeed :) My brain somehow never jumps to that option :p

Comment: `const_cast` is ugly, but virtually guarantees only one assembly implementation, which is nice.

Comment: Question, why can't I simply write `template<typename T, typename R = std::conditional_t<std::is_const_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>>, const int *, int *>> auto extract(T &input) -> R { return reinterpret_cast<R>(input.p + 12); }` Sorry for the formatting.

Comment: You could but then the template will accept [any type](https://godbolt.org/z/1qjvxb), instead of being constrained to just `S` with some cv-ref qualifications. The 2nd template parameter is for constraining the argument, while the stuff after `->` is to adjust the return type.

Comment: You might want something like `template <typename T, typename U> using copy_const_t = typename std::conditional<std::is_const<T>::value, const U, U>::type;`, to allow for `-> copy_const_t<T, int> *`

Answer (score 1):

`if constexpr` and `auto` as return type solution:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct S {
    int *p;
};

template<typename T>
auto extract(T &&input) {
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<decltype(input)>,S>, , "Only struct S is supported");
    if constexpr(!std::is_const_v<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(input)>>) {
        return input.p;
    } else {
        return const_cast<const int*>(input.p);
    }
}

int main () {

    S i;
    using t = decltype(extract(i));
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<t,int*>);

    S const i_c{0};
    using t_c = decltype(extract(i_c));
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<t_c,const int*>);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if moving the `is_same_v` to the template clause (as cigien did) so that only instance of `S` can call `extract()`?

Comment: I provided a `static_assert` at the beginning of the function to provide this check. You can add a message for the user in it. I provided my solution in order to show another way of writing templates (possible since C++17) - in my opinion, it is more straightforward and explicit. I don't want to say it is better, it is just different.

Answer (score 0):

PLZ look at the ISO proposal:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4388.html

And the `std::experimental::propagate_const` spec:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const

Or one can implement his own version of `propagate_const`.

have fun,
FM

Comment: So they finally make it that you can overload functions with only return type signature different? Not exactly related to the question, but nice read! Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

SFINAE should be able to do this.  The approximate format is:

```
template<class T, 
    class allow=std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<S, T>>>
auto extract(T&& input) -> decltype(input.p) {
    return input.p;
}
```

Basically using universal forwarding references to make it work for anything: S, S&, const S&, S&&, volatile S&, etc.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. `decltype(input.p)` is `int*` regardless of whether `S` is const or not.